# How to draw reverse stealth arrow on a segment

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want to draw a symbolic version of a lens: a segment with an arrow on both sides.

My code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\midarrow}{\tikz \draw[-triangle 60] (0,0) -- +(.1,0);} %voor pijltjes
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing} %cirkelsector?
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds,snakes}
\usetkzobj{all} %om hoeken te markeren?
\usepackage{mathtools}



\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[ymin=0,ymax=5,xmin=0,xmax=10]
\tkzClip
%\tkzGrid
\tkzDefPoints{5/0.5/A, 5/4.5/B, 3/0.5/C, 3/4.5/D}
\tkzDrawSegment[stealth-stealth, thick](A,B);
 \draw[>-<, thick]        (C)   -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image]

My questions are:

1) on the right side I used the stealth-stealth option, which is good (enough), but I want that the same on the left side but reversed (I hope the question is clear).

2) It would even be better if the arrows are a little bigger and straight (instead of curved like the left version.

(I also looked at pst-optics but for some reason it's giving troubles with the tufte-class and I had to change to many options to make it exactly the way I want.)

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `>=stealth, >-<`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I am interpreting your question as "I want to use stealth arrow tips and use the `>-<` arrow specification".

This is easy to accomplish by using the `>` key:

```
\tkzDrawSegment[>=stealth,>-<, thick](A,B);
```

2) There are many arrow tips in the `arrows.meta` library documented in Section 16.5 of the PGF Manual.
Look for the `Straight Barb` one maybe that's what you are looking for.
Section 16.3 gives you full details on how to customise the size and appearance of tips.

Comment: Didn't knew that I could use these two options together! Thanks